# Hiding a Div till clicked, and not hiding again once clicked again

Tags: javascript, jquery

So, once the button is clicked it reveals the information.

Which is great and what I need to be done, but say the user inputs some other information and wants to get a different set of information, it'll re-hide the info.

Hopefully that is enough context.

Basically I don't want the Jquery to run a second time. Just for the one click and not another..

Jquery:

```
$("#userSubmit").click(function() {
    $("#hidden").toggle();
});
```

CSS:

```
#hidden {
  display: none;
}
```

Comment: Have you seen jQuery's `.one()` method?

Comment: Or you could use  $("#hidden").show()

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Used:

```
    $("#userSubmit").one("click", function() {
    $("#hidden").toggle();
});
```

Accomplished what I was trying to get done.

Answer (score 0):

```
   <script>
    $(document).ready(function(){
      $("button").click(function(){
        $("div").toggle();
      });
    });
    </script>

<div>This is a paragraph.</div>
<button>hide() and show()</button>
```